# Different colour bars in a flot bar graph, is this possible?

Tags: javascript, graph, flot

I have looked through the documentation and the only reference I can find is for different colour **series**. However I have only one data series and would like points/bars on that series different colours.

I could use multiple series and make points set to zero, which would have the same effect.

Is there a supported mechanism for having different colour bars in a bar graph using flot ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't built in support for using multiple colors in a single series.

> Flot only allows specifying colors of the dots at the dataseries level, meaning each color must be its own dataseries. With this in mind, the solution is to make a single dataseries for each color.

Answer (score 4):

There is a Flot plugin that allows you to set the color based on threshold values that you set.  You can get the plugin code here:  https://github.com/subhrajitroy/Flot-plugin/blob/master/jquery.flot.threshold.multiple.js

Comment: Excellent link - playing with this plugin now.

Answer (score 3):

Flot is now shipped with a plugin that does just that.

Internally it splits a series into several series and assign a different color to each.

The plugin is in flot's github page here:
https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/jquery.flot.threshold.js